# Monaco Editor: Cannot find module 'monaco-editor' but it's installed

Tags: javascript, npm, monaco-editor

I'm making a desktop application using electron and I decided to use Monaco Editor and install it using `npm install monaco-editor` but when I run the application it says `Cannot find module 'monaco-editor'`

I used `electron-react-boilerplate` as a boilerplate.

I tried both methods for [installing it using ESM](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/master/docs/integrate-esm.md)

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
      "name": "electron-react-boilerplate",
      "productName": "ElectronReact",
      "version": "0.17.1",
      "description": "Electron application boilerplate based on React, React Router, Webpack, React Hot Loader for rapid application development",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "concurrently \"yarn build-main\" \"yarn build-renderer\"",
        "build-dll": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config ./configs/webpack.config.renderer.dev.dll.babel.js --colors",
        "build-e2e": "cross-env E2E_BUILD=true yarn build",
        "build-main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./configs/webpack.config.main.prod.babel.js --colors",
        "build-renderer": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./configs/webpack.config.renderer.prod.babel.js --colors",
        "dev": "cross-env START_HOT=1 node -r @babel/register ./internals/scripts/CheckPortInUse.js && cross-env START_HOT=1 yarn start-renderer-dev",
        "flow": "flow",
        "flow-typed": "rimraf flow-typed/npm && flow-typed install --overwrite || true",
        "lint": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development eslint --cache --format=pretty .",
        "lint-fix": "yarn --silent lint --fix; exit 0",
        "lint-styles": "stylelint --ignore-path .eslintignore '**/*.*(css|scss)' --syntax scss",
        "lint-styles-fix": "yarn --silent lint-styles --fix; exit 0",
        "package": "yarn build && electron-builder build --publish never",
        "package-all": "yarn build && electron-builder build -mwl",
        "package-ci": "yarn postinstall && yarn build && electron-builder --publish always",
        "package-linux": "yarn build && electron-builder build --linux",
        "package-win": "yarn build && electron-builder build --win --x64",
        "postinstall": "yarn flow-typed && electron-builder install-app-deps package.json && yarn build-dll && opencollective-postinstall",
        "postlint-fix": "prettier --ignore-path .eslintignore --single-quote --write '**/*.{js,jsx,json,html,css,less,scss,yml}'",
        "postlint-styles-fix": "prettier --ignore-path .eslintignore --single-quote --write '**/*.{css,scss}'",
        "preinstall": "node ./internals/scripts/CheckYarn.js",
        "prestart": "yarn build",
        "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production electron ./app/main.prod.js",
        "start-main-dev": "cross-env HOT=1 NODE_ENV=development electron -r @babel/register ./app/main.dev.js",
        "start-renderer-dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config configs/webpack.config.renderer.dev.babel.js",
        "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 jest",
        "test-all": "yarn lint && yarn flow && yarn build && yarn test && yarn build-e2e && yarn test-e2e",
        "test-e2e": "node -r @babel/register ./internals/scripts/CheckBuiltsExist.js && cross-env NODE_ENV=test testcafe electron:./ ./test/e2e/HomePage.e2e.js",
        "test-e2e-live": "node -r @babel/register ./internals/scripts/CheckBuiltsExist.js && cross-env NODE_ENV=test testcafe-live electron:./ ./test/e2e/HomePage.e2e.js",
        "test-watch": "yarn test --watch"
      },
      "lint-staged": {
        "*.{js,jsx}": [
          "cross-env NODE_ENV=development eslint --cache --format=pretty",
          "git add"
        ],
        "{*.json,.{babelrc,eslintrc,prettierrc,stylelintrc}}": [
          "prettier --ignore-path .eslintignore --parser json --write",
          "git add"
        ],
        "*.{css,scss}": [
          "stylelint --ignore-path .eslintignore --syntax scss --fix",
          "prettier --ignore-path .eslintignore --single-quote --write",
          "git add"
        ],
        "*.{html,md,yml}": [
          "prettier --ignore-path .eslintignore --single-quote --write",
          "git add"
        ]
      },
      "main": "./app/main.prod.js",
      "build": {
        "productName": "ElectronReact",
        "appId": "org.develar.ElectronReact",
        "files": [
          "app/dist/",
          "app/app.html",
          "app/main.prod.js",
          "app/main.prod.js.map",
          "package.json"
        ],
        "dmg": {
          "contents": [
            {
              "x": 130,
              "y": 220
            },
            {
              "x": 410,
              "y": 220,
              "type": "link",
              "path": "/Applications"
            }
          ]
        },
        "win": {
          "target": [
            "nsis",
            "msi"
          ]
        },
        "linux": {
          "target": [
            "deb",
            "rpm",
            "snap",
            "AppImage"
          ],
          "category": "Development"
        },
        "directories": {
          "buildResources": "resources",
          "output": "release"
        },
        "publish": {
          "provider": "github",
          "owner": "electron-react-boilerplate",
          "repo": "electron-react-boilerplate",
          "private": false
        }
      },
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate.git"
      },
      "author": {
        "name": "Electron React Boilerplate Maintainers",
        "email": "electronreactboilerplate@gmail.com",
        "url": "https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org"
      },
      "contributors": [
        {
          "name": "Vikram Rangaraj",
          "email": "vikr01@icloud.com",
          "url": "https://github.com/vikr01"
        },
        {
          "name": "Amila Welihinda",
          "email": "amilajack@gmail.com",
          "url": "https://github.com/amilajack"
        }
      ],
      "license": "MIT",
      "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/issues"
      },
      "keywords": [
        "electron",
        "boilerplate",
        "react",
        "redux",
        "flow",
        "sass",
        "webpack",
        "hot",
        "reload"
      ],
      "homepage": "https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate#readme",
      "jest": {
        "testURL": "http://localhost/",
        "moduleNameMapper": {
          "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/internals/mocks/fileMock.js",
          "\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
        },
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "js",
          "jsx",
          "json"
        ],
        "transform": {
          "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
        },
        "setupFiles": [
          "./internals/scripts/CheckBuiltsExist.js"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator": "^7.3.2",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
        "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/register": "^7.4.0",
        "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
        "babel-jest": "^24.5.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
        "babel-plugin-dev-expression": "^0.2.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
        "chalk": "^2.4.2",
        "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "cross-spawn": "^6.0.5",
        "css-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "detect-port": "^1.3.0",
        "electron": "^4.1.3",
        "electron-builder": "^20.39.0",
        "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
        "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.11.2",
        "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
        "eslint": "^5.16.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
        "eslint-config-erb": "^0.0.2",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
        "eslint-formatter-pretty": "^2.1.1",
        "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.11.0",
        "eslint-plugin-compat": "^3.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.4.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.4.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
        "eslint-plugin-testcafe": "^0.2.1",
        "fbjs-scripts": "^1.2.0",
        "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "flow-bin": "^0.95.1",
        "flow-runtime": "^0.17.0",
        "flow-typed": "^2.5.1",
        "husky": "^1.3.1",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
        "jest": "^24.5.0",
        "lint-staged": "^8.1.5",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
        "opencollective-postinstall": "^2.0.2",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
        "prettier": "^1.16.4",
        "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "sinon": "^7.3.1",
        "spectron": "^5.0.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "stylelint": "^9.10.1",
        "stylelint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.3",
        "testcafe": "^1.1.0",
        "testcafe-browser-provider-electron": "^0.0.8",
        "testcafe-live": "^0.1.4",
        "testcafe-react-selectors": "^3.1.0",
        "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
        "webpack": "^4.29.6",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.1.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1",
        "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1",
        "yarn": "^1.15.2"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.8.1",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.2.1",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "connected-react-router": "^6.3.2",
        "core-js": "2",
        "devtron": "^1.4.0",
        "electron-debug": "^2.1.0",
        "electron-log": "^3.0.4",
        "electron-store": "^4.0.0",
        "electron-updater": "^4.0.6",
        "history": "^4.9.0",
        "monaco-editor": "^0.19.2",
        "monaco-editor-webpack-plugin": "^1.8.2",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
        "react-hot-loader": "^4.8.2",
        "react-panelgroup": "^1.0.7",
        "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
        "react-resize-observer": "^1.1.1",
        "react-router": "^5.0.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
        "react-simple-resizer": "^1.3.1",
        "react-tabs": "^3.1.0",
        "react-virtualized-auto-sizer": "^1.0.2",
        "react-window": "^1.8.5",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-promise-middleware": "^6.1.1",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "shell-quote": "^1.7.2",
        "source-map-support": "^0.5.11",
        "ssh2": "^0.8.5",
        "xterm": "^3.14.5"
      },
      "devEngines": {
        "node": ">=7.x",
        "npm": ">=4.x",
        "yarn": ">=0.21.3"
      },
      "collective": {
        "url": "https://opencollective.com/electron-react-boilerplate-594"
      },
      "browserslist": "electron 1.6"
    }
```

I tried with no luck using different versions of `monaco-editor` and `monaco-editor-webpack-plugin` as suggested [here](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin/issues/91)

This is my webpack config, well the webpack.config of `electron-react-boilerplate` is kind of messy and maybe there is the error, here is a [link](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/tree/master/configs) of all the config files for webpack used by `electron-react-boilerplate` I've only changed that file thought.

```
    /**
     * Base webpack config used across other specific configs
     */

    import path from 'path';
    import webpack from 'webpack';
    import { dependencies } from '../package.json';

    const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

    export default {
      externals: [...Object.keys(dependencies || {})],

      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                cacheDirectory: true
              }
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'ts-loader'
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
          }
        ]
      },
      // entry: {
      //  // "app": './index.js',
      //  // Package each language's worker and give these filenames in `getWorkerUrl`
      //  "editor.worker": 'node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker.js',
      //  "json.worker": 'node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/json/json.worker',
      //  "css.worker": 'node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/css/css.worker',
      //  "html.worker": 'node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/html.worker',
      //  "ts.worker": 'node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker',
      // },

      output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app'),
        // https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1114
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
      },

      /**
       * Determine the array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
       */
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.json']
      },

      plugins: [
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
          NODE_ENV: 'production'
        }),
        new MonacoWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
      ]
    };
```

For completeness, I'm importing Monaco Editor like so: `import * as Monaco from 'monaco-editor'` if I use `import * as monaco from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api";` it works but without most of the features that I need.

Answer (score 8):

Add Jest config `'moduleNameMapper'`:

```js
'monaco-editor':
  '<rootDir>/node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.d.ts',
```

Comment: solved my problem by importing the js file like 
`node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.js`

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```js
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor'
```

Or:

```js
mport { editor, Uri /* , ... */ } from 'monaco-editor'
```