# Failed to install reactide " Error: Cannot find module 'vs/editor/contrib/gotoSymbol/goToCommands' "

Tags: npm, webpack, reactide

I try to install `reactide` on `Windows 10`. After cloning its [git repository](https://github.com/reactide/reactide) and installing dependencies. When I run the command `npm run webpack-production` I get the following errors:

```
C:\reactide(3.0-release -> origin) (reactide@3.0.0)                                                     
λ npm run webpack-production                                                                            
                                                                                                        
> reactide@3.0.0 webpack-production                                                                     
> webpack --mode production                                                                             
                                                                                                        
C:\reactide\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:281                                                     
                                throw err;                                                              
                                ^                                                                       
                                                                                                        
Error: Cannot find module 'vs/editor/contrib/gotoSymbol/goToCommands'                                   
Require stack:                                                                                          
- C:\reactide\node_modules\monaco-editor-webpack-plugin\out\index.js                                    
- C:\reactide\webpack.config.js                                                                         
- C:\reactide\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js                                        
- C:\reactide\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js                                                       
- C:\reactide\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js                                                       
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)                       
    at Function.resolve (C:\reactide\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:164:23)          
    at resolveMonacoPath (C:\reactide\node_modules\monaco-editor-webpack-plugin\out\index.js:34:28)     
    at C:\reactide\node_modules\monaco-editor-webpack-plugin\out\index.js:173:63                        
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)                                                                          
    at createLoaderRules (C:\reactide\node_modules\monaco-editor-webpack-plugin\out\index.js:173:43)    
    at MonacoEditorWebpackPlugin.apply (C:\reactide\node_modules\monaco-editor-webpack-plugin\out\index.
    at webpack (C:\reactide\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:51:13)                                  
    at processOptions (C:\reactide\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:272:16)                          
    at C:\reactide\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:364:3                                            
    at Object.parse (C:\reactide\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:576:18)                                    
    at C:\reactide\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:49:8                                             
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\reactide\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:366:3)                       
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)                                       
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)                         
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)                                            
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)                                  
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)                                        
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)                                               
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\reactide\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:156:2)                       
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)                                       
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)                         
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)                                            
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)                                  
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)               
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {                                                       
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',                                                                             
  requireStack: [                                                                                       
    'C:\\reactide\\node_modules\\monaco-editor-webpack-plugin\\out\\index.js',                          
    'C:\\reactide\\webpack.config.js',                                                                  
    'C:\\reactide\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\utils\\convert-argv.js',                             
    'C:\\reactide\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\cli.js',                                             
    'C:\\reactide\\node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js'                                              
  ]                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                       
npm ERR! code 1                                                                                         
npm ERR! path C:\reactide                                                                               
npm ERR! command failed                                                                                 
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "webpack --mode production"                       
                                                                                                        
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                                                    
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-08T13_47_50_402Z-debug.log
```

I tried looking for the solution on this [GitHub page](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin/issues/92) and this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802492/monaco-editor-cannot-find-module-monaco-editor-but-its-installed) but no success. I have installed all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs in `monaco-editor-webpack-plugin` used in `webpack.config.js`:

```js
plugins: [
  new MonacoWebpackPlugin(),
],
```

I found this [issue in official repo](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin/issues/92) with a similar error and I fixed the problem like this:

```js
plugins: [
  new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
    features: ["!gotoSymbol"],
    languages: ["!abap"],
  }),
],
```